# A python based PowerShell?

Tags: python, bash, powershell

I just took a brief look at PowerShell (I knew it as Monad shell). My ignorant eyes see it more or less like a hybrid between regular bash and python. I would consider such integration between the two environments very cool on linux and osx, so I was wondering if it already exists (ipython is not really the same), and if not, why ?

Comment: Do you have any citation saying that PowerShell is a hybrid of anything at all, much less a hybrid of bash and python? Re "bash", you may be confusing the fact that there are aliases like "rm" with it being like bash.

Comment: I meant that to me it looks like that, not that it is, and similar functionalities could be achieved with a mixed "bash/python-like" environment. I don't use win, so I have no real clue about its real functionalities.

Comment: Ok. Do either python or bash have the concept of an object pipeline? Like the standard unix shell pipes, but sending actual objects instead of a text stream?

Comment: No, Powershell is pretty unique in terms of its functionality. The "why" bit can be answered easily enough too: *nix hackers would never accept it if it requires any more typing than what they currently use.

Comment: @John: no they haven't. That's why I am asking, because I would like to have something similar on *nix.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Seems the first step to implementing this would be to find a scripting language that allows one script to send an object to another script.

Comment: I love Linux and I love Powershell, which is why I love this question and seek a similar solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've only dabbled in Powershell, but what distinguishes it for me is the ability to pipe actual objects in the shell.  In that respect, the closest I've found is actually using the IPython shell with `ipipe`:

- [Using ipipe](http://wiki.ipython.org/Using_ipipe)
- [Adding support for ipipe](http://wiki.ipython.org/Cookbook/Adding_support_for_ipipe)

Following the recipes shown on that page and cooking up my own extensions, I don't often leave the IPython shell for bash.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

I think Hotwire is basically what you're thinking of:

http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/wiki/GettingStarted0700

It's a shell-type environment where you can access the outputs as Python objects.

It doesn't have all PowerShell's handy hooks into various Windows system information, though.  For that, you may want to literally integrate Python with PowerShell; that's described in [IronPython In Action](http://www.ironpythoninaction.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as PowerShell on Linux or OSX, see [Pash](http://igorshare.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/pash-cross-platform-powershell-is-out-in-the-wild-announcement/), a cross-platform version of PowerShell using Mono.

Comment: ... which is *very* far from being functional, let alone complete and it hasn't seen an update in a year and a half.

Comment: +1 with the hope that someone would pick up any of these attempts to create a Linux friendly Powershell-like solution.

Answer (score 1):

An open source version of powershell does now exist. It can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell.

Comment: Thank You very much. I understand what you are saying. Net result is that the examples in the powershell 'help' should be used with caution.  I actually posted the question before I saw your response/comment. I will learn how to link this answer to the question I posted.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though, right?

Comment: Probably an error of judgement on my part as I added a question to my comment (pseudo answer). The response from  mklement0 is very helpful to me.  I posted the question a separate item. I will find my question post and link or copy the answer that was relevant to me to aid readers.

Comment: The question Chris mentions is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39823655/45375). I've removed my comments here and posted them as an answer there.