# Is there a reason for the different behaviour of PowerShell aliases 'ls' and 'dir' between the windows and OS X implementations

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

Does anyone know the reason for the difference in output between the below 2 cases?

The output from alias `ls` differs from the output of alias `dir` on OSX. In an example shown in the PowerShell help for `Help Get-Content -Examples`  :

```
dir ./*.txt | foreach {Get-Content $_ -Head 1; Get-Content $_ -Tail 1}
```

works as per the example. However, if `dir` is replaced with `ls`:

```
ls ./*.txt | foreach {Get-Content $_ -Head 1; Get-Content $_ -Tail 1}
```

an error is returned:

> ls: ./*.txt: No such file or directory

Both the above cases give the same result in PowerShell v5 on Windows 10.

Is this observation a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be invoking the command `/bin/ls` (`/usr/bin/ls`?) rather than the PowerShell alias `ls`, even though an alias should take precedence over an external command. Verify that the alias is actually defined:

```
Get-Alias -Name ls
```

Answer (score 3):

**Built-in aliases in the *Windows-only* edition named for *standard Unix utilities* were intentionally left out of the cross-platform editions, so as not to shadow (override) them.**

<sup>Note: This is **true as of PowerShell Core v6.0.0-alpha.10**, but this design decision has attracted controversy - find the discussion [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/929).

One notable pitfall is that PowerShell doesn't perform globbing when invoking *external* utilities, so something like `ls *.txt` doesn't work as it would in Bash, for instance.</sup>

Thus, alias `ls`, built into the Windows-native edition, is *not* built into the Linux & macOS editions, because standard utility `/bin/ls` should take precedence there.

By contrast, `dir` - due to not conflicting with any standard Unix utility name - is a built-in alias in *all* editions (and refers to `Get-ChildItem`, as on Windows).

When PowerShell was Windows-only, adding aliases such as `ls` (for `Get-ChildItem`) and `cat` (for `Get-Content`) was a nod to people coming from Unix backgrounds.
On Windows, these command names have no predefined meaning, but on Unix-like systems they would shadow standard utilities (CLIs), resulting in potentially unexpected behavior.

The safe, portable approach is to stick with:

- using the full cmdlet names instead of aliases.
- and/or using aliases solely based on *cmdlet* names (rather than on legacy command names such as `ls` or `dir`).

PowerShell has naming conventions for aliases derived from cmdlet names, mapping each approved verb (such as `Get-` and `Copy-`) to an approved alias prefix (such as `g` and `cp`) - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx.

When in doubt about what a given command name refers to, use `Get-Command <name>` (or `gcm <name>`).